# Plot the marginal effect of different regressions in one graph

Tags: graph, regression, stata, marginal-effects

I am running the same `probit` regression five times but on different sets of data.

How can I plot the curve of the marginal effects for each regression on the same graph to compare them in an easy way?

Below is the code I have tried:

```
probit one_y_unemp year* MR* AG* if Qualifica2 == 1
margins, dydx(year*) saving(me_intern, replace)

probit one_y_unemp year* MR* AG* if Qualifica3 == 1
margins, dydx(year*) saving(me_seniormanager, replace)

probit one_y_unemp year* MR* AG* if Qualifica4 == 1
margins, dydx(year*) saving(me_whitecollar, replace)

probit one_y_unemp year* MR* AG* if Qualifica5 == 1
margins, dydx(year*) saving(me_bluecollar, replace)

probit one_y_unemp year* MR* AG* if Qualifica6 == 1
margins, dydx(year*) saving(me_juniormanager, replace)

combomarginsplot me_intern me_seniormanager me_whitecollar me_bluecollar me_juniormanager, ///
labels("Intern" "Manager" "White Collar" "Blue Collar" "Junior Manager") xtitle("Years")
```

The problem I have with this code is that the graph I obtain, instead of having one curve for each professional role and having the year dummies on the x-axis, has one line per each year dummy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the *community-contributed* command `coefplot` instead:

```
sysuse auto, clear
estimates clear

egen price2 = std(price)
egen rep782 = std(rep78)
replace rep782 = rep78 * -10

regress mpg i.foreign##c.price2 rep78
margins, dydx(foreign) at(price2=(-3(0.5)3)) post
estimates store m1

regress mpg i.foreign##c.rep782 price2
margins, dydx(foreign) at(rep782=(-3(0.5)3)) post
estimates store m2

coefplot m1 m2, at
```

[image]